# I need to restore AD Default Domain Controllers Policy to default but cannot log in

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

Okay, long story.

I only have two domain controllers, I know, bad choice, but that's just what I did.

Microsoft just released the RD Web Client, so I wanted to install it. I created a new VM and joined it to my domain. Once I installed the Remote Desktop Web Client, it worked, except I couldn't use the Connection Broker because its service was starting and stopping. I found that it had something to do with the policies in Computer config > Windows Settings > Local security options > User rights assignment.

I went into that section and found the policy that the site listed to change that was about Generating Security Audits and one about Logging on as a Service to both allow Local Service and Network Service. That did not fix it for me.

This is where I went insane, please do not mind me, I regret everything I did.

I thought, maybe I should try others in that policy list, so I tried the one about creating a Token Object.

It froze, took a while, and then said could not change policy. But even so, it still showed the changes I made. So I preceeded to change them back. Once again, it gave the error, but still changed. Then I noticed that it gave an error saying that the domain controller could not be contacted. The other couldn't either. The GPO Management then closed.

In my VMWare list, I then noticed that my primary domain controller had shut down. I looked at it, and it booted back up, and then it said Applying Security Policy and Default Domain Controllers Policy, and then it said Please wait for Local Session Manager, then shut down again.

It is now in a boot loop.

I found something here "http://www.sysadminlab.net/windows/restore-default-domain-policy-and-default-domain-controller-gpo-settings-to-default", but I can't do it on Startup Repair options because it does not support Windows PE.

I tried Safe Mode, Safe mode with networking, and Safe mode with Command Prompt. Nothing.

I tried Last Known Good Configuration, nothing.

I also tried Directory Services Repair, but it can't complete the command because "it is not a domain controller". If I try to log in to a domain account instead in Directory Services Repair, it says the log on server could not be contacted.

I have tried everything I could think of, and I CANNOT afford to lose my AD Domain.

Also, if you come up with a solution, please take into account that I have an Exchange 2010 server hosted on that DC too, and can't afford to lose that either.

Also, the domain controller that won't boot is running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Furthermore, the RD domain controller DOES boot and log in, I'm not sure what's different. But do you think it's worth it to do the reset of policies on it?

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: So you cannot log into your domain controller using the default domain administrator credentials? Have you by any chance created any other domain administrator accounts whose credentials might be cached on that server? Are you also saying that even though this server is a domain controller, Domain Services Restore Mode is not working because it thinks that it is no longer a DC?

Comment: I cannot log into ANY account, because it shuts down before logon. The only time I can log into an account is when I boot in DSRM but it states, yes, that it isn't a domain controller, even though it obviously knows that it is because when logging in it specifically states that it is logging into my domain (INTERNAL). Yes, I do have two other accounts in the Admins group, but once again, same issue, because if I state any admin account to log in in DSRM, it says the server can't be contacted, and on the regular bootup, it just shuts down before logon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you can try is power off the damaged domain controller, mount the damaged domain controller disk on the functional domain controller, and copy the contents of the policy folder that you changed from the functional DC disk. Then reattached the disk to the damaged DC and start it.

`C:\Windows\SYSVOL\sysvol\[domain]\Policies\{Guid of the policy that you changed}\`

The offending file is probably the \MACHINE\Microsoft\Windows NT\SecEdit\GptTmpl.inf

I believe the line you are looking for should look like:

SeCreateTokenPrivilege =

If the computer is crashing before applying the policy that you changed, it may not work.

Comment: OP would have to recover the file from  the backup, I believe both DCs are toast.

Comment: The permanent GUID of the DDCP is {6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}

Comment: I actually just booted into the recovery mode and deleted the {6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9} policy folder in SYSVOL. The server now boots up. Thanks for the policy name, Semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Alright guys, I fixed it. I had to boot into recovery mode (WINPE), and I went into CMD, and removed the policy faulty policy {6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9} as Semicolon stated, and the server booted back up. Thanks very much.

Comment: Nice work!  Just curious about something... in the main description you said Win PE not supported on your servers, and in the solution you said you booted to Win PE.  Thx.

Comment: What I said, is that Windows PE is not supported by dcgpofix. But manually deleting files off of the hard drive is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you are lucky there is a VMWare snapshot you can restore from.  In the future you should consider taking a VMWare snapshot every time you are making any significant changes on a server.  Of course you need to remember to remove the snapshot once it is confirmed the changes are successful, as VMWare snapshots cannot be kept long term unfortunately.

Otherwise hopefully you can restore from your backup software.  Please tell us someone is doing regular scheduled backups in your environment.

Comment: The short version of this comment is, "do not take snapshots of domain controllers!"

Comment: Okay, yes, I have backups, from a software called Vembo, but I only like to use them when ABSOLUTELY nescessary, as when I restored from them once, the Exchange mail server could not send OR receive, and some policies had to be completely started over.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you missed this tidbit in the [Windows Documentation for the Create a token object user right](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/create-a-token-object) - (which you read before you adjusted the GPO that you didn't understand)

> [Create a token object] is used internally by the operating system.
>   Unless it is necessary, do not assign this user right to a user,
>   group, or process other than Local System.

Honestly, given your apparent level of experience, you need to get out your credit card, call Microsoft and open a case to see if they can help you resolve this.

---

You *may* be able to edit the DDCP group policy file manually if you use something like a live distro to boot into and access the drive.  I've *never* tried anything like that on a Domain Controller before, so YMMV.

Or instead of editing the file manually, you can obtain a previous copy of the GPO from your backup, and using a live CD linux distro to replace the current DDCP gpo with the older DDCP gpo file - may want to do that on *both* domain controllers, though.

---

Failing that, you may have to bite the bullet restore the DC from a backup.